# Transit visa required for Iranian flying from Turkey through London to USA?

Tags: uk, transit, transit-visas, us-residents, iranian-citizens

I'm an iranian citizen with having Iranian passport and USA permanent resident visa currently in Turkey for a visit and have a return flight to USA.

Below is information about my return flight to USA and according to that I have a question please:

My return flight to USA is a transit flight from Antalya AYT airport to London Gatwick airport with Thomas cook airlines and then my next flight is on the same calendar day and at the same airport  (London Gatwick) with Norwegian Airline which I have confirmed flight ticket for my onwarding flight. So my final destination is USA.

I need your assistance with my question please about whether or not I need any other travel documents like transit visa for my transit flight from Antalya AYT airport to London Gatwick airport with Thomas cook airline?

Comment: Note that if you have two separate tickets, you _must_ leave the secure area and go through immigration and customs into GB, simply to be able to re-check your luggage with Norwegian.